# Best way to link models together

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have a robot with multiple tools that can be hot-swapped during operation. Now I want to implement this tool changing also in gazebo (gazebo >= 6) but I'm not really sure what the best way is to achieve this.

Both `robot` and `tool` model are spawned individually based on a URDF description. When the tool shall be changed, I will probably delete the `tool` model, spawn the new `tool` model and then link `tool` and `robot` together.
These are the approaches that I have stumbled upon so far:

- Link the two models by joining them with a fixed joint
- `tool` model needs to have exact pose before doing this
- Attach the `tool` as static model via `physics::Model::AttachStaticModel()` to the `robot` model
- `tool` model has only fixed joints, but if spawned as URDF it is not shown as static in gazebo
- Add the `tool` model as sub model to the `robot` model (nested models)
- possible on the fly? If so, how to specify the pose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13890/best-way-to-link-models-together/) by [Hans-Joachim Krauch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2536/hans-joachim-krauch/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. It shouldn't be necessary to delete and respawn the tool for joint creation purposes.
2. The fixed joint method seems to me the most appropriate one. And you're correct, the relative pose which the tool has with respect to the robot the moment the joint is created will be maintained. You can calculate the pose you want and move the tool to that pose before attaching the joint.
3. Static models don't respond to physics, so I'm not sure this is what you would want here.
4. Note that nested models are not necessarily fixed to each other. Just like links in a model, they'd need a joint to hold them together. So using a nested model might help organizing things, but you'll still need to create a fixed joint.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0